# spliting string from a line and appending in a list in python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, text

I have a file which contains with following format in each line I want to write a function which gets the keyword "Main value" and searches for it and gives output.

File format:

```
Main value:value_name,value (1):value_name1,value (2):value_name2 and so on...
```

Output required:

```
Feature name: Main value
Technical name: value_name
Possible values: value_name1
                 value_name2
                 value_name3 and so on...
Possible variables: value (1)
                    value (2)
                    value (3) and so on...
```

Code till now:

```
def get_feature_infos(file_path, feature_name):
    technical_name = []
    possible_variables = []
    possible_names = []
    with open(file_path, "r") as commands_library:
        for line in commands_library:
            if feature_name in line:
                technical_name.append((line.split(",")[0]).split(":")[1])
                possible_variables.append(line.split(",")[1].split(":")[0])
                possible_names.append(line.split(",")[1].split(":")[1])

        print ("   Technical name: ", technical_name[0])
        print ("   Possible values: ", possible_variables[0])
        print ("   Possible variables: ", possible_names[0])
```

But this prints only the first possible values but I want all the possible values

Comment: what about  `value` after `value_name`?

Comment: your file contains all these on one line?

Comment: It is _getting_ all the data but you are only _printing_ the first. Change your printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It worked for me:

```
def get_feature_infos(file_path, feature_name):
    technical_name = []
    possible_variables = []
    possible_names = []
    data = []
    with open(file_path, "r") as commands_library:
        for line in commands_library:
            if feature_name in line:
                technical_name.append((line.split(",")[0]).split(":")[1])

            data = (line.split(","))
            data.pop(0)

            for shortData in data:
                possible_variables.append(shortData.split(":")[0])
                possible_names.append(shortData.split(":")[1])

        print ("   Technical name: ", technical_name[0])
        print ("   Possible variables: ", possible_variables)
        print ("   Possible names: ", possible_names)
```

Comment: This actually worked with little alteration from my side: I added the following lines to the answer `name_length = len(possible_names)
  variable_length = len(possible_variables)
  
  print ("   Technical name: ", technical_name[0])
  print ("   Possible GUI options: ")
  for i in range(0, name_length): 
   print ("                        " + possible_names[i])
  print ("   Possible variables: ")
  for i in range(0, variable_length): 
   print ("                      " + possible_variables[i])`

Comment: I am glad, it helped you. Yes, you will need `for` loops to discard the `[ ]`.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you are looking for is a way to print a list of values in a list regardless of how the list is named.  What you can do is to create a text list.  For example:

```
print ("   Technical name: ", ', '.join(technical_name))
```

You may also want to transpose the output by creating tuples before you print:

```
tups = zip(*(technical_name, possible_variables, possible_names))
for tup in tups:
    print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(tup))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce the second argument of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) - `maxsplit` to you.

With `maxsplit`, you can split "Main value" and the rest:

`feature_name, rest = line.split(':', 1)`

then the value_name and the rest:

`technical_name, rest = rest.split(',', 1)`

then possible_variables and possible_names

```
possible_variables = [x.split(':')[0] for x in rest.split(',')]
possible_names = [x.split(':')[1] for x in rest.split(',')]
```